# the click shows all objects. and I only need one

Tags: lua, love2d

i have a click function and there are 4 objects and i want this click function to show these objects one by one. but alas I have all 4 objects showing up at once. as I show them one by one on each click. For example 1 click one object. second click another object

```
function click()
   for index = 1, 4 then
    SHOW(index)
   end
end
```

Comment: What scripting system this code is written for: corona, love2d, some game engine, etc.?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff love2d

Comment: Make global variable `button_index = 1` and replace the loop with `SHOW(button_index); button_index = button_index%4 + 1`

Answer (score 1):

In `love.load()` put the line

```
showTracker = 1
```

Then, replace your `click()` function with

```
function click()
    if showTracker <= 4 then
        SHOW(showTracker)
        showTracker = showTracker + 1
    end
end
```

You're creating a global variable in `love.load()` to track which pictures you've already displayed. Then when `click()` is called it draws the next picture, if there're any pictures left to draw.